# can I lose data if I downgrade cpu,ram, or disk on a vm instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I have installed some go binaries on a vm instance on google compute cloud. A few hours later I noticed that I could improve underutilized compute power as per google cloud recommendation. So I did. I downgraded to a single core and decreased ram on that particular vm. Not disk space as far as I can remember. I then tried to look up those binaries and some dependencies that I had previously installed but they're gone. My question is: Did I lose data on the vm because of the downgrade? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

If it's a local disk, [just by restarting the machine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/local-ssd#data_persistence) you can lose the data.

If it's a [persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk), since it's an independent entity from the machine, it will not affect that you change any other parameter (CPU, RAM, ...).

If you resize the disk, since [you can only increase it's size](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/disks/resize), you won't lose data.

Unless you have un-attached a persistent disk, you used a local SSD, or you had a ramdisk mounted, you have not lost any data. Try `find` to look for your binaries.

Comment: Great! That helped a lot! Thanks!